# Remote Ubuntu Installation

Tags: server, remote

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a remote server ?
I had to move to where my server is situated to install Ubuntu last night, which thing is not very funny.

Comment: You could probably get an image and set up something that way, like a specific partition size maybe? You might be able to do something with Clonezilla in this sense. http://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later

Comment: I know about Clonezilla but I would love to be able in the futur to intstall Ubuntu remotely.

Comment: There is this answer too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/225693/what-are-the-easy-ways-to-install-ubuntu-remotely where you have someone push dd through an open port on the server (kinda remote.. but you would need someone on other end to accept/have system set up) I was thinking  about you putting an image on a PXE as well then just loading that way, but again another problem. Not sure about the normal need of people doing Server installs, or are you doing desktop through server?