# How do i login to an account from another computer like windows?

Tags: login, users, accounts

How do i log into a server computer from another computer like you can do on windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to remote login on a Ubuntu machine from ubuntu/windows and OSX](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5075/best-way-to-remote-login-on-a-ubuntu-machine-from-ubuntu-windows-and-osx)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to connect to a windows server or ubuntu/linux server? 
Generally, you can use `ssh` to log into a remote server (if an `ssh` server is running in `remote host`) by:

`ssh remote_username@remote_host`